# ¿Por qué mi label no refresca la imagen a pesar de que ha cambiado?

Tags: java, java-swing, netbeans-8.2, icons

Comunidad Stack.

Necesito que alguien me ayude con este problema que no entiendo por qué sucede.

La cuestión es que tengo una aplicacion que genera un reporte y muestra en un label una imagen dentro de una ventana. A continuación el código:

```
public class VentanaReporte{

    String path;    

    public VentanaReporte(String path) {

        this.path = path;                
    }

    public void abrir() {
        JFrame ventana = new JFrame("Reporte");
        JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane();
        JLabel etiqueta = new JLabel();

        //Le pasó la ruta de la imagen
        Icon imagen = new ImageIcon("Reportes//TablaHash.jpg");        

        etiqueta.setIcon(imagen);

        ventana.getContentPane()
                .add(scroll);

        scroll.setViewportView(etiqueta);

        ventana.pack();

        ventana.setVisible(true);
    }

}
```

Pero resulta que al crear la imagen a partir de un archivo .dot de graphviz me abre la correcta la primera vez, pero cuando ese archivo se modifica, porque el .dot ha cambiado, es cuando falla porque me sigue abriendo la imagen que se generó anteriormente, sin importarle que la imagen si cambió en la ruta de origen.

Es como si la imagen quedara en "cache" y cargara la primera que se generó por predeterminado.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Después me vuelve a mostrar esta misma imagen aunque la imagen del archivo original ya no sea la misma.

El código que utilizo para abrir la ventana es:

```
    //Nombre del archivo que deseo abrir
    String nombreImagen = "TablaHash.jpg";

    //Ventana que administra la imagen (codigo arriba)
    VentanaReporte reporte = new VentanaReporte(nombreImagen);
    reporte.abrir();
```

La ruta en donde se encuentra mi imagen es dentro del proyecto.

Además, si quisiera abrir la imagen con el visor de imagenes del SO y uso:

```
    try {
        File imagen = new File(path);
        Desktop.getDesktop().open(imagen);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Ocurrió un problema. El archivo no existe");
    }
```

Si me abre la correcta cada vez que la imagen cambia.

Si alguien me puede ayudar agradecería bastante la respuesta. Si necesitan más información escribirla en los comentarios. Saludos.

Comment: no probaste setear nuevamente el icono del `JLabel etiqueta` luego que la imagen cambia?. Otra pregunta, por qué haces `etiqueta.setIcon(null);`?

Comment: Buen dia @JuanRom, pues técnicamente hago ese set en **etiqueta.setIcon(imagen)** . Ahora lo del **null**. Es algo que estaba haciendo antes y olvidé quitarlo. Aun así, implementando metodos get y set el resultado es el mismo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La forma que encontré para resolver fué la siguiente

```
 String ruta = "src//UI//Reportes//imagen.png";
        BufferedImage bimg;
        try {
            bimg = ImageIO.read(new File(ruta));
            int width = bimg.getWidth();
            int height = bimg.getHeight();

            //Ventana que almacena la imagen
            ScrollPanel s = new ScrollPanel(ruta, width, height); 
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Drive.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
```

En primer lugar lo que se hace es obtener las dimensiones de la imagen que ha cambiado para poder ajustarla al visor de imágenes que abre el ScrollPanel

```
public ScrollPanel(String ruta, int ancho, int alto) {
    super("JScrollPane Demo");       
    Image image = new ImageIcon(ruta).getImage();        
    ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(image.getScaledInstance(ancho , alto, Image.SCALE_SMOOTH));                
    JScrollPane jsp = new JScrollPane(new JLabel(icon));
    getContentPane().add(jsp);
    setSize(1000, 600);
    setVisible(true);
}
```

El form **ScrollPanel** recibe la ruta y las dimensiones.
Se crea una **Image** para obtener la imagen y se le pasa a un **ImageIcon** para insertarla en el label. ¡Ojo! es importante que el constructor del **Imageicon** este escrita de esa forma porque si solo se le envía **image**, no refrescará.

Como enviamos las dimensiones de la imagen podemos crear una versión a escala. Y así mantendremos la relación de aspecto.

Mandamos la imagen al **ScrollPane** que puede tener cualquier tamaño y ahora la imagen ya se actualizará cada vez que cambia en la ruta enviada.

Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

podrias probar con lo siguiente:

```
ImageIcon image = new ImageIcon(imgPath);
image.getImage().flush();
this.imgLabel.setIcon(image);
```

Comment: Por favor, añade una explicación de que es lo que hace tu código